# git - duplicate parent

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I seem to have managed to have a commit with two duplicate parents using eGit (Eclipse's git client, powered by JGit).

[image: SS]

The 2nd parent causes that green 'branch to nowhere' that we can't get rid of.

I've been googling ways to perform some surgery on the commit to remove the extra parent, 
but to no avail.

Running cat-file I get:

```
$ git cat-file -p 26dc6a5b44373f766d81513ab84c5eecaf876736

tree 527df208ee66f52bc414948b1de0fa6607cfb81c
parent bc9d55d0451b325b4ad5a758be8b30c1418b3af9
parent bc9d55d0451b325b4ad5a758be8b30c1418b3af9
author Roy Truelove <roy.truelove@xxxx.com> 1316457571 -0400
committer Roy Truelove <roy.truelove@xxxx.com> 1316457571 -0400
```

I'm sharing this repo and this problem has already been pushed, which I'm sure will contribute to the complexity of the solution..

Thanks git hackers,
Roy

PS - I do have command line access to this repository (cygwin) if I need to perform a function not available through eGit

Comment: Are you sure is not a bug in eGit?

Comment: Could be, but even if it were a bug in eGit, it's some funky state in the repo itself that's being represented badly by eGit.  If I could fix that funky state it should solve the issue.

Comment: What's git cat-file -p <commit> say for that commit?

Comment: drizzd - Thanks - I added the output of cat-file to the question

Comment: Do you happen to know if the commit in question was made using EGit/JGit or using command-line Git?

Comment: Ok. That's most likely a bug in egit. I have not seen this in C git before. They have a bug tracker here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All

Comment: I faked a commit like yours but I cannot reproduce the graphical effect with git version 1.7.6.1. But maybe it only happens with the particular structure of your history.

Comment: @KevinSawicki - They were created with eGit

Comment: Can you give the date of the commit to try and pin down the version of EGit/JGit where this occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the history; the duplicate parent will automatically be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the duplicate parent from the commit you can do this:

```
git replace <sha1> $(git cat-file commit <sha1> | uniq | git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin)
```

The commit with the duplicate parent has been temporarily replaced with a new commit that does not contain the duplicate parent. You can check if the gitk display problem has gone away now.

In order to permanently replace the commit you can use git filter-branch. Note that at that point you will have rewritten history. All developers working on this project must be made aware of this, so that they can also rebase/reset their local work/copies to the new history.

Comment: Thanks Drizzd - I ran that command on a copy of repository - it created a replacement (git cat-file -p <replacementSHA1> has only one parent) but when I load the repository up in eGit, it still shows both parents.  Perhaps eGit doesn't support replacement commits.. (?)

Comment: Yes, eGit probably does not support it. In fact, I did not even realize that your problem was with eGit and not with gitk. Either way, after filter-branch, the problem should be gone. And according to Josh's answer, filter-branch will fix this particular issue automatically, even if you do not create the replacement commit.