# git duplicate parent causes half the history to to disappear

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I ran a `git filter-branch` to rename some authors in my git repository and I get:

```
$ git log --oneline | wc -l
665
$ ./git-rename-author.rb "First Last" new-email@email.com old-email@email.com
Rewrite 453a72b4f690620c04fce80a0aa237b9dee7038f (653/665)error: duplicate parent f61ea265c9069723f58557c55d3efae450ab2bd0 ignored
Rewrite 566c89fd59cf7e5c2992ee11adbf876343dc4a85 (665/665)
$ git log --oneline | wc -l
339
```

So whole I start off with 665 commits, I end with 339.

Looking at the [git - duplicate parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501703/238292) answer, it seems `git filter-branch` should resolve the duplication itself. Is that what the resolution is? Are there 326 duplicate commits?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: here's the `git filter-branch` script I run. It's a simple Ruby script to rename multiple email addresses into one user.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ARGV[2].split(',').each do |old_email|
  puts "Renaming #{old_email} to #{ARGV[0]} <#{ARGV[1]}>"

  env_filter = <<-EOS
  '
  an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
  am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
  cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
  cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

  if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "#{old_email}" ]
  then
      an="#{ARGV[0]}"
      am="#{ARGV[1]}"
  fi
  if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "#{old_email}" ]
  then
      cn="#{ARGV[0]}"
      cm="#{ARGV[1]}"
  fi

  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
  '
  EOS

  system "git filter-branch -f --env-filter #{env_filter}"
end
```

Comment: Rewriting is (potentially) destroying data for good. Handle with care.

Comment: what filter-branch script did you run?

Comment: @Chronial posted the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may already have a commit that has the same parent twice; `git filter-branch` with no filters specified will detect this and repair it. Try this first, before making any author changes.

You may also have a commit with a pair of parents that are currently distinct but which will be identical after transformation by your `filter-branch` script. If your `filter-branch` command is correct then you haven't lost any work - you just had a parallel set of pre- and post- rewrite commits in your history which are now unified.

Comment: I ran `git filter-branch` with no filter and still at 665 commits. However, your explanation makes sense. When I compare with the number of commits this repository has in Subversion (where it was converted from), it seems that the 300 number is more accurate. Thanks!